# In React is passing a component directly to another component allowed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, react-functional-component

I am new to react and was wondering if you are allowed to directly pass one or more components to another instead of passing it as a prop or child.

Consider the following:

```
const ChildComponent = () => {

  return (
    <h1> I am a child </h1>
  );
}

const ChildComponent2 = () => {

  return (
    <h1> I am also a child </h1>
  );
}

//Passing directly to Parent
const ParentComponent = () => {

  return (
    <div>
         <ChildComponent/>
         <ChildComponent2/>
    </div>
  );
}


//Passing as children
const ParentComponent2 = ({ChildComponent, ChildComponent2}) => {
    return (
      <div>
         {ChildComponent}
         {ChildComponent2}
      </div>
    );
}

<ParentComponent>
    <ChildComponent/>
    <ChildComponent2/>
</ParentComponent>
```

I have read about passing components as children vs props. I have also seen that it is an antipattern to create functional components inside of functional components. I can't seem to find anything about directly passing one or more components inside of another without using props or children. When testing it out, the component rendered properly, but I am not sure if it's a valid way of passing components to a parent component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With React's composition model, you can take advantage of the special `children` prop to pass children elements directly.

```
// With props object destructuring
const ParentComponent = ({children}) => {
  return (
    <div>
         {children}
    </div>
  );
}

// Without props object destructuring
    const ParentComponent = (props) => {
      return (
        <div>
             {props.children}
        </div>
      );
    }
```

This lets you pass other components as children to the parent component by nesting the JSX:

```
// A pair of children components
const ChildComponent1 = () => {
  return <div>I am child 1</div>;
};

const ChildComponent2 = () => {
  return <div>I am child 2</div>;
};

// Compose your parent component with its children
const App = (props) => {
    return (
      <ParentComponent>
         <ChildComponent1 />
         <ChildComponent2 />
      </ParentComponent>
    );
}
```

As per the React docs, this is the recommended way of composing your components.

As a final thought, sometimes you might need specialized components or partials and perhaps not make use of children but always render a specific component.

Comment: But is there any consequences to passing a child component directly to the parent component like I did in my first example listed under the comment "Passing directly to Parent"

Comment: In my opinion, no problem at all.

The example you're referring to may fall under the umbrella of the case I wrote at the end of my answer: you want to have a parent component that renders a specific component / set of components.

You're not violating React's composition model.
Those components you're explicitly passing to ParentComponent are still formerly known as children.

Hope I was helpful :)